# Is it possible to remove a row in MySQL based on a column having a specific character in the string?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table, and for this purpose say the database name is 'A_blah', that has several columns but i am interested in removing rows based on a specific column containing a string with a certain character. An example would be say there is a column containing:

```
A
A{
B
B{
AA
AA{
```

What i am looking to do is to remove each row that has '{' in the string in this column leaving:

```
A
B
AA
```

Is this possible with a query and if so could you show and explain? Thank you so much.

Comment: delete from A_blah where columnname like '%{%' should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that's the only character your dealing with a simple:

```
DELETE FROM A_Blah WHERE col LIKE '%{%';
```

Should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use MySQL Regular Expression

```
DELETE FROM A_blah WHERE column_name REGEXP '[A-Z]*[{][A-Z]*'
```